# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: Compile Error

Tags: c++, c, compiler-errors

Newbie here.

Please see below the cut-down version of an encryption program. When all the code existed in a single file, it worked ok. Since splitting it up between three file, I get a compile error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>
> "encrypt(char*, int, char const*)", referenced from:
>
> _main in test-af8192.o
>
> : symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Individually compiling the files works without error. The error appears when linking.

From Googling, I see this error happens when you don't have your methods declared, but I believe they are. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

main.cpp

```
#include "encryption.h"

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
     //NOTE: Simplified code - data and characterCount exist at this point.

     char *encrypted = encrypt(data, characterCount, key);
}
```

encryption.h

```
#ifndef ENCRYPTION_H
#define ENCRYPTION_H

#include <stdlib.h> /* srand, rand */
#include <time.h>

char const key[] = "ABCDEFGHIJK";

char *encrypt(char data[], int dataSize, const char key[]);

#endif
```

encryption.cpp

```
#include "encryption.h"

/**
 Encrypt the passed in data array.
 */
char *encrypt(char data[], int dataSize, const char key[])
{
    int e = 0;
    char *encrypted = new char[dataSize];

    for (int i = 0; i < dataSize; i++)
    {
        encrypted[e++] = data[i] + key[i];
    }
    return encrypted;
}
```

Comment: Please show the commands you use to compile. Are you sure that you want to compile this as `c++` sources? It looks like it is plain C.

Comment: gcc test.cpp -o test.o -c     gcc encryption.cpp  -o encryption.o -c      gcc -o enc test.o encryption.o.      Am doing as c++ as going to be part of a bigger project.

Comment: You could try g++ instead of gcc

Comment: Thanks Thomas. As simple as that. Not sure I understand why GCC didn't work, but great stuff!